# fread() reading too much data

Tags: c, file, io

Currently I am trying to read a binary file 16 bytes at a time.  This is great until the end of the file where it reads a full 16 bytes regardless of whether the file has ended or not.  I have a file with "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV" written into it and it reads "QRSTUVGHIJKLMNOP" on the second pass after successfully receiving the first 16.  How can I stop it from re reading those bytes?  This is what I have currently.  It obviously does not print the second pass of data because fread does not return 16. I should note I MUST read 16 bytes at a time.

```
#define BS 16
unsigned char buffer[BS];                               // for storing each 16 bytes read
int i = 0;                                              // for iterating through readbytes

while (fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ifp) == BS) {
    while (i < BS) {
            printf("Read: %c\n",buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
}
```

Comment: "It  obviously does not print the second pass of data". Which means it is not the actual code that has the problem. Please provide that exact code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suspect your print code may be the problem but can't say for sure unless you show the problematic code.

Comment: In case it is not clear. What I mean is that you think the problem is "fread reading too much data". But that is very very unlikely. What is more likely is that you have some other problem - such as printing the entire buffer regardless of how much `fread` has read (ie, not correctly using the `fread` return value). But that's just a guess and need to see your full code to be sure.

Comment: It doesn't reread the bytes `GHI…NOP`; they are still in the buffer from the previous successful read.  When `fread()` reports a short read, the contents of the buffer after the data it reports reading are indeterminate.  You need to save the return value from `fread()` — it's a `size_t` — and use that to guide you.  It reports 6 bytes; accessing anything after that leads to undefined behaviour.  (You should define `int i = 0;` inside the outer `while` loop; then you wouldn't need the trailing `i = 0;` after the inner loop.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler or even just use a standard `for` loop. Or  `printf("Read %16.16s", buffer);`

Comment: @M.M — yes,you're right.  The loop printing the characters is fine — as long as it's a single-byte code set (not UTF-8, for example).  Similar comments apply to using `%16.16s` — you need to be confident that the data doesn't have null bytes etc in it.  For the sample data, no problem — for other data, that could be a problem.  Even `%c` isn't entirely satisfactory for UTF-8 or null bytes, etc.

Comment: When the file is read from, the data from the last pass is leftover in buffer.  I think what I am trying to say is that I would like to know how to tell when the data from the current pass is done being read.  I am trying to print each byte from the binary file into a new file except I don't know how I can tell when the data is actually finished.  I could loop for the amount of data read from the return of fread, but I haven't yet seen an example online doing this which makes me wonder if I am doing something wrong and could be doing something more efficient.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but the [fread man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) tells you exactly how to know that you have reached the end of the file: "If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).". That is, if `fread` returns less than `BS` you know you have reached the end of the file (or some other error has occured).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't reread the bytes `GHI…NOP`; they are still in the buffer from the previous successful read.  When [`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) reports a short read, the contents of the buffer after the data it reports reading are indeterminate.  You need to save the return value from `fread()` — it's a `size_t` — and use that to guide you.  It reports 6 bytes; accessing anything after that leads to undefined (unspecified, indeterminate — generically 'undesirable') behaviour.

*You should define `int i = 0;` inside the outer `while` loop; then you wouldn't need the trailing `i = 0;` after the inner loop.  Or even just a routine `for` loop, as [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889787/fread-reading-too-much-data/59889958#comment105908212_59889787).*

Hence:

```
#define BS 16
unsigned char buffer[BS];
size_t nbytes;

while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ifp)) == BS)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BS; i++)
        printf("Read: %c\n", buffer[i]);
}

printf("Short read (%zu bytes):\n", nbytes);
for (size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i++)
     printf("Short: %c\n", buffer[i]);
```